# Usedrange Resize VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have used the following code to copy and data from various excel worksheets in a selected file and paste to a separate consolidated data workbook.

It's working fine but I would like to copy and paste the text from the worksheets without including the first row (or header).

I guess I need to resize the used range selection.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
Sub Data()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [Sheet1!A2]

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Report", _
FileFilter:="(.xls),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
Exit Sub

Else

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
    With Sheet.UsedRange
        .Copy PasteStart
        Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
    End With
Next Sheet

End If

wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheet.UsedRange.offset(1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
    With Sheet.UsedRange
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count-1, .Columns.Count).Copy PasteStart
        Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count-1)
    End With
Next Sheet
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question (this answer was in the Low Quality Posts review queue).

Comment: The answer only introduces one new concept on top of the posted code: I don't believe that merits elaboration.